# Synchronizing nested views in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

My "root" state includes two views that exist for the entirety of the application:

```
  //index.html 
  <body ui-view> 
      <under-pane ui-view = "underpane"></div>
      <over-pane ui-view = "overpane"></div>
   </body>
```

The `underPane` and `overPane` directives have templates that include static elements which are present in all states, and each also includes its own `ui-view`.

```
//directives.js
.directive('overPane', function(){
     template: '<div ... ><div ui-view="overpaneView"></div></div>'
     //...
 }).directive('underPane', function(){
      template:'<div ... ><div ui-view="underpaneView"></div></div>'    
     //...   
 })
```

These "nested" UI-views are the primary targets of my application states, each of which  loads a different element into each of them:

```
//app.js          
}).state('foo', {
   views: { 
     'overpaneView@':{ } //loaded into the ui-view nested in the overPane directive 
     'underpaneView@' : { }     
    })
```

***What might be the cleanest way to keep these views synchronized in each state?***
As I understand it, I can't use controllers on the states, because controllers are not instantiated unless templates are loaded, and templates are overridden when a state has a `views` property.

That said, I'm very attracted to the `resolve` function of `ui-router`, and I'm thinking of organizing my strategy around it:
Each state's resolve function determines what data is needed based on the state parameters, then injects that data into separate controllers for each view, which *will* be instantiated with those views.
If I put this data either in a service or on a shared scope, I can then use two-way data-binding to keep the two views in sync.

***Right?***

- Are there any pitfalls I might be overlooking with this method?
- Is there a simpler method I'm overlooking?
- Would you consider it an "angular way" of doing this?
  (I'm doing this all as a learning exercise as I try to wrap my head around angular)

Answer (score 0):

You will run into much work, if you want to have the states and data synced.

Maybe just put the logic of those 2 subviews into 1 controller.

index.html

```
<body>
  <div data-ng-view>
  </div>
</body>
```

Route config:

```
$routeProvider
   .when(ROUTES.LOGIN, {
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
      controller: 'DashboardController'
    })
```

The view (dashboard.html):

```
<div ng-include="templateOfOverpaneView"></div>
<div ng-include="templateOfUnderpaneView"></div>
```

The DashboardController will then contain the logic for both views. 
The $scope within the controller will be available for both included templates.

This approach will remove necessity of sync states and data.